# Why the following template doesn't compile?

Tags: compiling, theorems

I'm using the following template for publication in "issue in proceedings volumes in the Gruyter Proceedings in Mathematics series" but it doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[11pt,notitlepage,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\leftmargin -2cm
\textwidth 16cm \oddsidemargin -0.01cm \evensidemargin -0.01cm
\addtolength{\textheight}{2cm} \addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgflibraryarrows}


\usepackage{tikz}
%%%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%%%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%%%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
%%%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}


%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{showkeys}
\newcommand{\pa }{\partial}
\renewcommand{\a }{\alpha }
\renewcommand{\b }{\beta }
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta }
\newcommand{\media}{\mkern12mu\hbox{\vrule height4pt depth-3.2pt width5pt} \mkern-16mu\int}
\newcommand{\laplconf}{L_{g}}
\newcommand{\qi}{q_i}
\newcommand{\yi}{y_i}
\newcommand{\vi}{v_i}
\newcommand{\wi}{w_i}
\newcommand{\ui}{u_i}
\newcommand{\D }{\Delta }
\newcommand{\Di }{\mathcal{D}^{1,2}(\R^n_+) }
\newcommand{\e }{\varepsilon }
\newcommand{\g }{\gamma}
\renewcommand{\i }{\iota}
\newcommand{\graffe}[1]{\parent \{ \}{#1}} % racchiude il testo tra graffe adeg.
 \newcommand{\foral }{\forall\, }
\newcommand{\G }{\Gamma }
\renewcommand{\l }{\lambda }
\renewcommand{\L }{\Lambda }
\newcommand{\m }{\mu }
\newcommand{\n }{\nabla }
\newcommand{\var }{\varphi }
\newcommand{\rh }{\rho }
\newcommand{\s }{\sigma }
\newcommand{\Sig }{\Sigma}
\renewcommand{\t }{\tau }
\renewcommand{\th }{\theta }
\renewcommand{\o }{\omega }
\renewcommand{\O }{\Omega }
\newcommand{\z }{\zeta }
\newcommand{\ov}{\overline}
\newcommand{\wtilde }{\widetilde}
\newcommand{\wk}{\rightharpoonup}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\hf}{\hfill $\diamondsuit$}%\medskip}
\newenvironment{pf}{\noindent{\bf Proof.}\enspace}{%\rule{2mm}{2mm}
\hfill Q.E.D. \medskip}
\newenvironment{pfn}[1]{\noindent{\bf Proof of {#1}\enspace}}{%\rule{2mm}{2mm}
\hfill Q.E.D. \medskip}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\Vert {#1} \Vert}
\newcommand{\salt}{\noalign{\vskip .2truecm}}
\newcommand{\parent}[3]{\left #1 {#3} \right #2} % racchiude il testo tra il
                                                                                                                                                                                                         % primo e secondo simbolo\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\parent (){#1}} % racchiude il testo tra tonde adeguate
\newcommand{\quadre}[1]{\parent []{#1}} % racchiude il testo tra quadre adeguate
\newcommand{\barre}[1]{\parent \Vert \Vert {#1}} % racchiude il testo tra barre adeguate
\newcommand{\Rs}{\mbox{ \scriptsize I\hspace{-.15em}R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Zs}{\mbox{\scriptsize Z\hspace{-.25em}Z}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
\newcommand{\BX}{\mathbf{B}(X)}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{Remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}[section]
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{Example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}

% MATH -------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeindex
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%\usetikzlibrary[patterns]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\begin{remark}
If there exists 
\end{remark}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{999} A., Spectral theory
and applications of linear operators and block operator
matrices, Springer-Verlag, New-York, (2015).

\end{thebibliography}


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Somebody gave you a -1 because this site's purpose is not to debug peoples code but to answer to specific questions and to help the latex community and not just any user's specific problem. Also the error you get is "! LaTeX Error: Environment remark undefined." that is a very clear error (You would not get that -1 if you was referring to a specific error and had searched for this before the question)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know the difference between Remark environment (with capital R), and  remark environment. And the answer is very helpful for me.

Comment: I am not the one that downvoted... I am the one that explained... Also if you don't stay at the first part of my comment you will see that I am trying to help you not to get a minus again by making more clear questions in title and body... You, also, can edit this one and I am sure it will be upvoted after have a title and a body on this issue and thus not being (or seems to be) a "debug my code" question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. It says `LaTeX Error: Environment remark undefined`.

The problem is that you are defining a `Remark` environment (with capital R), and using a `remark` environment.

You can either change the definition of your `remark` to:

```
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
```

or use a `Remark` environment with capital R:

```
\begin{Remark}
  Remarked stuff
\end{Remark}
```

Comment: but it exists `\newtheorem{Remark}{Remark}[section]`

Comment: Oh, I missed it. But notice the difference between `Remark` and `remark`. TeX is case sensitive! Updated my answer.